# What do the last characters of a conda package's name mean?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm fairly new to python and got myself familiar with how to set up project in python (via virtual environments) and how to reference other project with pip or Anaconda.
Looking into the Anaconda repository, I realized that packages/libraries contains of the name, version and an odd looking number in the end.

[image: Screenshot of Anaconda repository]

So my question is, what does this set of characters of an arbitrary length indicate? Is it like a specific build from that version? If so, why are there difference between the same version? Shouldn't it be a new version?

Comment: `vc9` can means it was compiled using (Microsoft) **V**isual **C** / **C** ++ **9**.0

Comment: Ah thank you! So which compiler is used for the 0 builds?

Comment: `0` is in `osx` version. I don't know compilers for osx but it may have only one compiler so number has no matter.

Comment: In addition to the answer in the duplicate, the `vcX` does indicate the version of the Visual C compiler used for the build. The `0` is an integer that is incremented when the recipe for the package changes, but the version of the underlying software does not change.